# Kotlin library project Failed resolution of: [Lkotlin/reflect/KProperty

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently building a library project which is written in Kotlin. When I export an `.aar` file and compile on a project, I get the following error refering to a `by lazy` lambda.

#### The error I'm having on the sample app

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.myproject.lib.MainActivity$view$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Lambda;
...
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: [Lkotlin/reflect/KProperty;
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.reflect.KProperty" on path: DexPathList
```

#### The line exception referring to in the library project

```
private val view: View by lazy {
      LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.overlay_view, this, false)
}
```

#### Gradle file of the library project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        androidExtensions {
            experimental = true
        }

    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin'
    }

    buildTypes {

        debug {
        ...
        }

        release {
          ...
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    api 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.22.2'
    api "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-coroutines:0.10.4"

    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    api 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'

    api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
    api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'

    api 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.5.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.json:json:20140107"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.13.0"
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-inline', version: '2.13.0'
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.13.0"
    testImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.9.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `aar` file is built without the dependencies of the project.

The solution I went for is to create private `maven` repository and publish my project with dependencies.

To add your dependencies to generated `pom.xml` file, you can modify your publish method with the `withXml` task in your module level `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
group = 'com.group'
archivesBaseName = 'group-sdk'
version = '1'

publishing {

    repositories {
        maven {
            url myMavenRepoWriteUrl
            credentials {
                username 'myMavenRepo'
                password myMavenRepoReadPassword
            }
        }
    }

    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {

            // Artifact properties
            groupId group
            version  version
            artifactId archivesBaseName

            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${archivesBaseName}-debug.aar")

            pom.withXml {
                //Creating additional node for dependencies
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

                //Defining configuration names from which dependencies will be taken (debugCompile or releaseCompile and compile)
                def configurationNames = ["debugCompile", 'compile']

                configurationNames.each { configurationName ->
                    configurations[configurationName].allDependencies.each {
                        if (it.group != null && it.name != null) {
                            def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)

                            //If there are any exclusions in dependency
                            if (it.excludeRules.size() > 0) {
                                def exclusionsNode = dependencyNode.appendNode('exclusions')
                                it.excludeRules.each { rule ->
                                    def exclusionNode = exclusionsNode.appendNode('exclusion')
                                    exclusionNode.appendNode('groupId', rule.group)
                                    exclusionNode.appendNode('artifactId', rule.module)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```